# Map pin does not show in MapKit after giving permission to the device

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

so i tried to show my location in mapkit, but somehow it does not show any of the pin in the map, even though I already gave my device the permission.

i tried to follow along a set of instruction in the internet, but still does not work at all, the pin wont show up.

Tried to zoom in, still no sign of any pin
[image: asking for permission]

[image: after giving permission]

What did I do wrong or miss? Thank you
My VC

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class AmbulanceCallViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let rootMap:MKMapView = {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
        mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return mapView
    }()
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(rootMap)
        checkLocationServices()
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rootMap.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            rootMap.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            rootMap.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

}

extension AmbulanceCallViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    }
}

extension AmbulanceCallViewController {
    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    
    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuth()
        } else {
            //show alert
        }
    }
    func checkLocationAuth() {
        print("Working on it...")
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("working la 1")
            rootMap.showsUserLocation = true
            break
        case .denied:
            print("working la 2")
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            print("working la 3")
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            rootMap.showsUserLocation = true
            break
        case .restricted:
            print("working la 4")
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("working la 5")
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("error, something wrong with the services")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any of the code in `setupLocationManager` or the delegates.  Just set the `showsUserLocation` property to `true` when you set up the map view and request `whenInUse` authorisation.

Comment: asuming that what i did is also true , why isn't it displaying any pin?

Comment: You are running on the simulator so you need to simulate a location in the simulator debug menu.  You can see from the location shown in the permission dialog that the default simulator location is in San Francisco. The simulator won't show your actual location because it doesn't have a GPS receiver.